# Can any one help me on this?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter, I am trying to implement a password change feature to my users, but I am getting the following error:

[image: error]

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue..I am stuuked on this
My Controller:

```
public function changePassword(){
            $data['title'] = 'Change Password';
            $this->load->model('register_model');
            if($this->register_model->authorized() == true){
        redirect(base_url().'ChangePass/changePassword');

            }
```

[My Model:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zrxvl.jpg)
My View:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
        <?php echo form_open('ChangePass/changePassword', array('user' => 'passwordForm'))?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="oldpass" id="oldpass" class="form-control" placeholder="Old Password" />
                <?php echo form_error('oldpass', '<div class="error">', '</div>')?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="newpass" id="newpass" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password" />
                <?php echo form_error('newpass', '<div class="error">', '</div>')?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" name="passconf" id="passconf" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                <?php echo form_error('passconf', '<div class="error">', '</div>')?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Change Password</button>
            </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: Your form submits to `ChangePass/changePassword`, then your changePassword function redirects to the same URL. I'd say either show a view instead of a redirect, or redirect to a whole new URL.

Comment: you are redirecting to the same url 
redirect(base_url().'ChangePass/changePassword');

Comment: you are doing `<?php echo form_open('ChangePass/changePassword',)` &    `redirect(base_url().'ChangePass/changePassword');` in same function.

Comment: Don't post code as images. All relevant code needs to be copy/pasted into the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because you are redirecting on the same method.

change this line

```
redirect(base_url().'ChangePass/changePassword');
```

to another address like

```
redirect(base_url().'ChangePass/done');
```

and there you can show your success message:

```
public function done(){
    $data['title'] = 'Change Password';
    $this->load->view('changePassword/done',$data);   
}
```

and there you can print your message

**done.php**

```
<?=$title?>
```

I hope this would help you